# Resize JButton within mu Jframe to put it on the bottom of the page horizantally

Tags: java, swing, resize, jbutton

```
  I need to write a code that generates library number and resize the JButton to put it to the bottom of the frame.
```

I need to write a code that generates library number from 1001 and each subsequent number should be one greater. Once the library number has been generated and shown in the text field, the button text should change to ‘Confirm’.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class HW4GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JButton jbtAction;
    private JTextField jtfFName;
    private JTextField jtfLName;
    private JTextField jtfLibNo;
    private int nextLibNo;
    private JPanel textPanel;

    public HW4GUI()   
    {
        setTitle("HW4 GUI");
        makeFrame();
        showFrame();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      I need to write a code that generates library number from 1001 and each subsequent number should be one greater. Once the library number has been generated and shown in the text field, the button text should change to ‘Confirm’.
    }

    public void makeFrame() Make frame method
    {       
        setLayout( new GridLayout(4,0) ); 
        jtfFName = new JTextField( 15 ) ; 
        JLabel aLabel = new JLabel("First Name: ");
        jtfFName.setActionCommand("First Name");
        jtfFName.setHorizontalAlignment(aLabel.RIGHT);

        jtfLName = new JTextField( 15 ) ; 
        JLabel aLabel1 = new JLabel("Last Name: ");
        jtfLName.setActionCommand("Last Name");
        jtfLName.setHorizontalAlignment(aLabel1.RIGHT);

        jtfLibNo = new JTextField( 10 ) ; 
        JLabel aLabel2 = new JLabel("Library Number: "); 
        jtfLibNo.setActionCommand("Library Number");
        jtfLibNo.setEditable(false);
        jtfLibNo.setHorizontalAlignment(aLabel2.RIGHT);

        add(aLabel);
        add(jtfFName);
        add(aLabel1);
        add(jtfLName);
        add(aLabel2);
        add(jtfLibNo);

        JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();
        jbtAction = new JButton("Add Borrower");
        jbtAction.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jbtAction, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        add(jbtAction); I need to resize this button 

        jtfFName.addActionListener( this );
        jtfLName.addActionListener( this );
        jtfLibNo.addActionListener( this );
        jbtAction.addActionListener( this );

    }

    public void showFrame()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setSize(400,200);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay, so now you've given us the requirements, whats the question?

Comment: atm my button is placed in left bottom corner of the frame I need to position my button text in the bottom center of the frame. I can upload the picture of the frame if that helps. I also need to write a code to the action performed method when the first name and laste name entered in the texfield the button must text must change to confirm and generate a number from 1001,1002,1003,1004 each time when the add borrower button is pressed.